# Interchangeable Regex field

Tags: regex

So I have a date field (YYYY/DD/MM)

```
^((\d{4}|\d{2})[-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/])(0?[1-9]|1[012])$
```

AND

(YYYY/MM/DD)

```
^(\d{4}|d{2})[-/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))$
```

I was wondering if I could make DD and MM parts interchangeable so that I don't represent them separately. I know I could use OR function after YYYY, but I really would like to have a regex that can capture both formats in a shortest pattern.

Comment: No. you can't. Exactly how do you plan to tell apart `2016/03/04` and `2016/04/03`? Both are completely valid, but March 4th and April 3rd are not exactly the same date. The **ONLY** way this could ever work is if you forbid anything to ever happen on days 1-12, so that only the 13th to 28th/29th/30th/31st is ever valid.

Comment: So you want to build conditional logic into the regex that will look ahead at the third \d\d in YYYY/MM/DD and try to determine if that really is a DD or just a MM? But as @MarcB writes, how will you discern when 07 is July or the 7th? what about 1997/07/07. How do you decide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to take regex1 and regex2 and throw them together like this:

```
regex1|regex2
```

Then, you can extract mutual "prefixes" and "suffixes". In your case:

`^(\d{4}|d{2})[-/]` and `$`

Here I use a `?|` branch reset:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{2})[-/](?|(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/](0?[1-9]|1[012])$|(0?[1-9]|1[012])[-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))$
```

Assuming that `\d` is for your purposes the same as `[0-9]`, you can shorten that a little:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{2})[-/](?|(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[-/](0?\d|1[012])$|(0?[1-9]|1[012])[-/](0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))$
```

This adheres the closest to your original regexes.

---

On the other hand, you may want to forgo some of the validation. The part that matches the day will also match all months.

This regex:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{2})[-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

If you don't care about capturing groups (since it is trivial to split on `[-/]`), you can use:

```
^(\d{4}|\d{2})([-/](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])){2}$
```

It will match everything the old regexes matched. The downside is that it also matches "dates" like:

```
2000/31/30
```

Of course, the shortest regex (within reason; otherwise it's `.*`) will be something like:

```
^(\d{2}){1,2}([-/]\d{1,2}){2}$
```